# Can I disable "click on the move" in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I have finally migrated to Windows 7. One source of perpetual annoyance is that I often "click on the move" on task bar icons expecting them to maximise back into view. More often than not, a left click on the move pops up the right-click menu instead. Bizarre. I'm not lost for words over what an incredibly bad user interface design decision this is (it's really hard to achieve unless you're good at bullseying womp rats in your T-15...) but I'll spare you the full rant.

I have given up trying to guess how Windows refers to this "feature". Can someone just please tell me how to disable it?

Comment: Can you clarify what's happening? Not sure what you mean by "click on the move". In Windows 7, when I click (left-click, as you say) an icon on the taskbar, the window toggles between minimized and visible.

Comment: If you left click and drag up you get the same menu as right clicking. No idea how to turn if off.

Comment: This is "Frustrated" here - still cannot properly login to any SE sites with Firefox 25.0.1. Thanks to Brian, I now realise that it is an unintentional side-effect of the click and drag up. If the mouse is moving up as you do a normal click, Win 7 interprets the click in one place and release a little higher as a click+drag. To my mind, drag needs to be much more deliberate - lasting at least 0.5sec. But I can't see any control over this. Still frustrated...

Comment: BTW, the menu that comes up is called a "Jump List". Doesn't answer your question, but it might help you ask it!

Comment: @Brian I was unaware of the click+drag behavior regarding the taskbar. I find it useful. "Frustrated", click and click+drag are 2 very distinct actions. Any delay in click+drag would be undesirable for many tasks. It seems you want click+drag to respond like a click. The only way I can think to accomplish that would be through a specific manufacture's mouse config software allowing scripting or configuring custom button actions. Not sure if Logitech or Microsoft mice have that specific config option. You might want to look at http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm

Answer (score 1):

The answer from the Microsoft site appears to be: No.

The reason for this functionality is so touch users can swipe up on a task bar button to open the jump list.